# Thank you for your continued support or continuous support?

Tags: word-choice

When you want to thank someone for the support they give you always. Which one should I use?

- Thank you for your **continued** support?
- Thank you for your **continuous** support?

Comment: But I have seen both are used. So, when to use the other one?

Comment: Let me guess, I feel continued support fits better even before I did a quick search on the Internet. A website writer said I cannot formulate a rule then said: "Universities have Departments of ***Continuing Education***, but they often ask their **contributors** for their ***continued support***." but I think I can [guess] if it's true! *Action in isolation (detached from the activator) = continuous support. Action attributed to the activator = use continued support.*

Answer (score 14):

"Continued support" is the standard verbiage that charities use when thanking their donors -- the idea behind it is that you're trying to encourage the donors to continue donating in the future. If you say "continuous support," you're thanking them for something that they have already done, but with no "incentive" to keep doing it.

"Continued," in a very unconventional way, implies an assumption (albeit wishful) that the supporter will continue to support **__** in the future. If that's what you're going for, then "continued" is the word you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

Thanking someone for 'continued support' is more logical since you are thanking them for support already rendered. Using 'continuous support' implies an assumption that support will not stop moving forward and thus continuous. So business wise, since there is no guarantee that support will be rendered continuously in the future, it is wise to officially thank them only for what they have already rendered. So 'continued support' seems more appropriate. My two cents.

Comment: Your answer is the opposite of the other answer. I'm now more confused.